# UML - What is relationship when a class instance is declared in method

Tags: oop, uml, relationship

I would like to know how the following relationship is called in UML and how it is marked on a class diagram ? Is that a constrained dependency relationship, marked by dotted arrow ?

```
public class A {}

public class B
{
    public foo()
    {
       A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. It's

```
B - - - > A
```

Comment: Thank you very much